# Get data from 2 tables based on comma separated values Join

Tags: join, csv

I am an average in database operation but I never deal with a database having values in comma separated manner. As I want the result from both table.

I have one table **"Form table"**

```
+------+-----------------+
| id   | Fname           |
+------+-----------------+
| 1    | BH01101,BH01102 |
| 2    | f_934_tarun2    |
| 3    | f_934,T_3234    |
+------+-----------------+
```

2nd table **"user assigned form table"**

```
+------+--------------------------------+
| u_id | Fname                          |
+------+--------------------------------+
| 1    | BH01102,BH16101,BH16102,BH16   |
| 2    | f_934_tar,f_934_fhh            |
| 3    | f_934_ttt,T_3234               |
| 4    | f_934_a1,BH01102               |
+------+--------------------------------+
```

I want to get all user ids who has any of form listed in form table. So here the output will be:

```
+------+
| u_id |
+------+
| 1    |
| 3    |
| 4    |
+------+
```

Every help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which RDBMS and version are you using? `CREATE TABLE/INSERT` would be helpful

Comment: @Charlieface MySQL 5.6

Comment: @ErgestBasha Its in production so there is no option to redesign as far now. I agree. but it was previously designed

Answer (score -1):

> I am an average in database operation ...

Clearly this table was designed by someone of *below* average ability.

> ... I never deal with a database having values in comma separated manner.

Nor *should* you.  This "design" is just plain *wrong*.

Your tables *should* look more like this:

```
select * from forms ; 

+------+--------------+
| id   | Fname        |
+------+--------------+
| 1    | BH01101      |
| 1    | BH01102      |
| 2    | f_934_tarun2 |
| 3    | f_934        |
| 3    | T_3234       |
+------+--------------+

select * from user_forms ; 

+------+-----------+
| u_id | Fname     |
+------+-----------+
| 1    | BH01102   |
| 1    | BH16101   |
| 1    | BH16102   |
| 1    | BH16      |
| 2    | f_934_tar |
| 2    | f_934_fhh |
| 3    | f_934_ttt |
| 3    | T_3234    |
| 4    | f_934_a1  |
| 4    | BH01102   |
+------+-----------+
```

Then your query becomes

```
select uf.id id 
from forms f 
inner join user_forms uf 
      on f.if = uf.u_id 
     and f.fname = uf.fname
group by uf.id 
order uf.id ; 

+----+
| id | 
+----+
|  1 | 
|  3 | 
|  4 | 
+----+
```

Go back to whoever dumped you with this *rubbish* and get them to sort it out.

Comment: No option to redesign as far now. and if you want to give solution, it would be great, but using a aggressive language will not help anybody.